# what is the proper query for insert and select statement with Like clause?

Tags: c#, mysql

i have this query and it gives me error which is unavaible to insert null on table tbl_emp_gs. i don't know what is wrong with my code here.

```
con.Open();
sqc = con.CreateCommand();
string query1 = "INSERT INTO tbl_emp_gs (EmployeeID,StepID) VALUES ('"+ lblEmpID.Text +"', (Select StepID from tbl_gradestep where StepID Like @grade))";
 sqc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@grade",cmbStepNumber.Text);
 sqc.CommandText = query1;
 sdr = sqc.ExecuteReader();
 MessageBox.Show("Data Saved.", "Message",MessageBoxButtons.OK,MessageBoxIcon.Information);
```

i want to get the step ID from tbl_gradestep table,

Comment: What is the table structure?

Comment: tbl_gradestep
"StepID"
"GradeNumber"
"StepNumber"
"SalaryGrade"


tbl_emp_gs
"StepID"
"EmployeeID"

Comment: Make sure @grade has % prefixed and suffixed. Else, append it manually as you are using LIKE.

Comment: @James-DeanLorenzoAlimboyogue Do you have `%` in your cmbStepNumber Text ?

Comment: @user3185569 yes i inserted it but gives me the same eror

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Inner query is returning `NULL`. You should follow `like` syntax in order to retrieve a correct result (If it exists) :

```
string query1 = "INSERT INTO tbl_emp_gs (EmployeeID,StepID) VALUES ('"+ lblEmpID.Text +"', (Select StepID from tbl_gradestep where StepID Like @grade))";

sqc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@grade", "%" + cmbStepNumber.Text + "%");
```

I suggest using `sqc.ExecuteNonQuery()` unless you have a valid reason to execute a data reader.

Also, it is not recommended to concat strings in SQL statements.

Comment: still NULL sir.

Comment: @James-DeanLorenzoAlimboyogue Are you sure you have data in your database that matches that condition ?

Comment: no it does not have matches, i should put SalaryGrade after where not StepID.

my Bad.
tried in sql server studio it gives me null
then i notice it should be salarygrade not stepID 

Then it gives me the StepID after changing to SalaryGrade.

Thank you Guys.

Comment: one more question. i got my lblsalary text formatted in culture info. but in my database it is just 12000. how can i format that back to 12000??

Comment: Please mark this as accepted if you find it helpful.. I did not get your last question.. If it is something not related, you can ask another separate question and put all the details with a complete example !

Comment: i need 15 reputation :((

Comment: @James-DeanLorenzoAlimboyogue Mark as accepted is different than up-vote.. Check how to do it here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235

Comment: ill try executeNonquery tomorrow sir, does execute reader is just for while?

Comment: @James-DeanLorenzoAlimboyogue Execute reader is used for Select statements. Execute non query is used for update, insert, delete, etc...

Comment: @user3185569 thank you for the wonderful explanation, i will always remember it.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a insert Select and not a values with select  .. 
in this way you perform the insert only if the select work  and if you have mode then on rows in select you insert the same number of rows

Assuming that @grade is   the search pattern

```
"INSERT INTO tbl_emp_gs (EmployeeID,StepID)
 SELECT ('"+ lblEmpID.Text +"', StepID 
from tbl_gradestep where StepID Like concat('%', @grade, '%'))"
```

Comment: concat supports on mySQL 5.6+ only i guess

Comment: @JonesJoseph   concat is at least  form 4.1   (is an SQL ansi 92 standard) http://ftp.nchu.edu.tw/MySQL/doc/refman/4.1/en/string-functions.html

Comment: errro near ',' sir.

Comment: show me all the error message text  .. (there are several , )  and please explain me what is @grade ..

Answer (score 0):

```
string query1 = "INSERT INTO tbl_emp_gs (EmployeeID,StepID) VALUES ('"+ lblEmpID.Text +"', (Select StepID from tbl_gradestep where StepID Like '%@grade%'))";
```

Comment: directly use like '%@grade%'

Comment: i'm not allowed to mark two answer at the same time :(

Comment: but he has a better answer plus  explanation :/ maybe after 24 hours, i guess i am allowed?

Comment: @James-DeanLorenzoAlimboyogue I don't care about marking answers. But this answer is pure evil ! You should never concatenate strings to build up a SQL Query as I mentioned in my answer. This is prone to SQL-Injection and should never be used in real projects ! There is a security issue here. I don't even know why this got selected. Does it provide a better solution ? No .. Was It answered faster ? No.. I see no reason. On top of that, this answer is misleading to anyone searching for a correct answer.

Comment: yeah. i need parametized query. ty :)